# How to run a git hook upon successful push to Github?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, githooks

I'd like to write a git hook to run some bash script when I push to my prod branch on Github. The bash I'm writing will essentially use aws command line tools to push an update to my app to AWS.

Can I do this with a pre-push or is there a post-push?

Answer (score 0):

[The githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) has a complete list of all hooks, and there is no post-push hook. You can do something in your pre-push hook, but there is a flaw: you can't tell whether the server is going to accept or reject the push, because your pre-push hook runs way too early, to let *you* abort the push, before they have even seen it.

Your best bet is to wrap the outer `git push` into a script: the exit status of `git push` tells you something about what succeeded, and/or you can query the remote (e.g., via `git ls-remote`) and see if its reference(s) have changed after the push.  (This has its own instance of *post hoc ergo propter hoc* fallacy, but is probably fine for your purpose.)

Comment: What about post-receive ? A valid hook after successful push

Comment: @OhadM: `post-receive` hooks are run in the receiving Git, not the pushing one. GitHub won't let you set an arbitrary post-receive hook as that would give you too much access to their computers. They do allow a very limited set of actions after a receive, but that's often the wrong way to solve the problem the OP wants to solve.

Comment: thanks, I've tried to git push during pre-push and got [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to lock) but, when looking at the commits in the remote, everything looks good. WDYT ?

Comment: "failed to lock" is an odd one, but "remote rejected" means that the other Git told your Git: "no, I won't set the ref name change you asked for". Check the hash IDs: a commit's true name is its hash ID.

Comment: I don't see any issue, hashes look god. Not sure what to check...